# How to use scalajs-bundler with client only app

Tags: npm, scala.js, scalajs-bundler

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42018476/16673) I was advised to use [ScalaJS bundler](https://github.com/scalacenter/scalajs-bundler) to import NPM dependencies.

I would like to use some Javascript NPM packages in a simple client-only web application. There is [an example called static](https://github.com/scalacenter/scalajs-bundler/tree/master/sbt-web-scalajs-bundler/src/sbt-test/sbt-web-scalajs-bundler/play) which shows this.
My changes to the example:

Add into build.sbt:

```
npmDependencies in Compile += "esprima" -> "3.1.3"
```

Add into Main.scala:

```
import Esprima._
import JsonToString._
val code = "answer = 42"
val tokens = tokenize(code)
val tokensStr = tokens.json
```

Change in `Main.scala`: `"This is bold"` into `s"This is bold $tokensStr"`

Facade (a bit simplified, for full a version see [GitHub](https://github.com/OndrejSpanel/ScalaFromJS/blob/npm/src/main/scala/Esprima.scala)):

```
import scala.scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation.JSName

@JSName("esprima")
@js.native
object Esprima extends js.Object {

  def tokenize(input: String, config: js.Any = js.native, delegate: String => String = js.native): js.Array[js.Any] = js.native

  def parse(input: String, config: js.Any = js.native): js.Dynamic = js.native
}
```

When running the html generated with `fastOptJS::webpack` the error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tokenize' of undefined

Inspecting the `static-fastopt-bundle.js` shows `esprima` is used, but its js is not bundled.

What other steps are needed to add dependencies into a client-only web page?

Comment: Asked as [#105](https://github.com/scalacenter/scalajs-bundler/issues/105) on `scalajs-bundler` GitHub.

Comment: You should also include the facade definition in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [this part](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalajs-bundler/cookbook.html#facade) of the documentation, you have to use `@JSImport` in your facade definition:

```
@JSImport("esprima", JSImport.Namespace)
```

For reference, `@JSName` defines a facade bound to a global name, while `@JSImport` defines a facade bound to a `require`d JavaScript module.

Comment: Great. A see a little drawback of needed a different facade depending on how I define the dependency, but at least it works. The package is the same. Is there some way to use the same facade for both webjars and bundler distributed package?

Comment: It seems e.q [jquery facade](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-jquery) does this. I will check it and perhaps add into this answer.

Comment: There is now a `JSImport` variant accepting a fallback when modules are not enabled, see https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/pull/2957. Great.